# Why pyautogui crashes while detecting mouse click

Tags: python

i want to make program when mouse clicked there is 1 second interval and then right mouse click. but i have some problem to make this program. when i use this code and mouse clicked, right mouse is click on it again

```
    import mouse
    import pyautogui
    while 1:
        mouse.on_click(lambda: pyautogui.rightClick())
```

when i use this code it repeats once, slows down, then stops.

```
  import pyHook
    import pythoncom
    import pyautogui
    import time
    def onclick(event):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.rightClick()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return True

    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDown(onclick)
    hm.HookMouse()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    hm.UnhookMouse()
```

I'd really appreciate it if you could give me a solution. thanks

Comment: Which platform are you using? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: @fez.tival I use Windows !